# ASP.Net Identity PasswordHash issue on two different web applications

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, .net-core, webforms, asp.net-identity

I have an existing .NET 4.5 Webforms web application that connects to a SQL Server database. I am using ASP.Net Identity. This website has been running for a few years now.

Onto my next project, I decided to create it in .NET Core 2.2 without EF. It uses the same SQL server database and Users table. All I am using is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI and I created my customer UserStore, UserRole classes. The login process works.

However, the login process on the .NET Core 2.2 application updates PasswordHash of the user. The initial login calls SetPasswordHashAsync and then updates the user via UpdateAsync. This then means the login no longer works on the Webforms application.

Comparing the two password hashes, the .NET Core 2.2 hash is longer, so does it use a generate it differently? Is there a way I can get both applications to use the same algorithm if so?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simple solution in the end, I just had to register the PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode to IdentityV2 in the Startup Configure method.

```
services.Configure<PasswordHasherOptions>(options => options.CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2);
```